# How to automatically login to a website using a shell script?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to know if there was a way to login to a website by specifying login credentials in a shell script and automatically login by running the shell script.

Comment: Are you using Firefox?  have you tried any of the script extensions?

Comment: @Srinivas Gowda if login to website automatically is **only** thing you want then I could help you. BTW which browser you use?

Comment: I use Firefox. And just to keep you posted I'd like to do this using a shell script not using the browser's save login and password method.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication

Comment: I think more info on what you are trying to achieve by logging in to a website is needed. i.e. are you downloading a file, or do you want your web browser to automatically be logged in to a site when you open it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lynx` to automate the login and it provides much more features.
Refer the man page of lynx [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/lynx.1.html)

`lynx` can be easily integrated with a shell script.
Using `lynx` with -auth parameter you can pass a id and password for authentication.

> -auth=ID:PASSWD set authorization ID and password for protected documents at startup. Be sure to protect any script files which use
>   this switch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `-auth=` is only for HTTP Basic Auth scheme which almost no website today uses.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `-auth=ID:PASS` didn't work.
So I used this:

```
lynx -cmd_log=/home/luk/lynxScript.lys -accept_all_cookies www.webside.com/auth
```

Then logged in, with a password.

As a result (save in the file `lynxScript.lys`), I got all the commands executed when logging in.

Now I could use this:

```
lynx -cmd_script=/home/luk/lynxScript.lys -accept_all_cookies www.webside.com/auth
```

- `-cmd_log` - saves your actions.
- `-cmd_script` - plays the recorded actions.

So with `-cmd_log` and `-cmd_script`, you can do everything you want on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what login mechanism the website uses, because there is no standard.

Most websites today use cookies. So basically you have to automatically fill in the login form, submit it, and store the cookie you get in return. Then you have to use that cookie in subsequent access to the site.

`curl` is a good tool for this. You have to write a script where you first call

```
curl -c /tmp/cookiefile -d login_field_name=login -d password_field_name=password https://site.domain/path/to/login
```

Of course `login_field_name`, `password_field_name` and `https://site.domain/path/to/login` (and maybe other parameters needed by login form) are things you must read from the page source.

After this succeeds, authentication cookie will be stored in `/tmp/cookiefile`, and you have to use it for subsequent accesses to the site:

```
curl -b /tmp/cookiefile http://site.domain/path/to/whatever/you/need
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `python` with [`mechanize`](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and `http.cookiejar`, e.g.:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import mechanize
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(self.cj)

br.open("http://www.example.com/")
br.select_form(id="loginform")
br.form["username"] = "myuser"
br.form["password"] = "mypassword"
br.submit()

# from now on, all requests to example.com uses your logged in user
br.open("http://www.example.com/some_acces_restricted_page")
```

Where [`br.select_form`](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html#mechanize.Browser.select_form) in the example uses the `id` from `<form id="loginform">` and username are the respective names of the fields within this form.